# Matlab - How to create table of unkown number of matrices with same size?

Tags: matlab

I would like to create table of unknown number of matrices with same sizes, so I can't do it like this:

```
table1 = table(zeros([5,5]),zeros([5,5]),zeros([5,5]), 'VariableNames', {'matrix1','matrix2','matrix3'});
```

But here I am stuck because I am not able to find out how to make this without listing zeros([5,5]) n-times, where I don't know what will n be so i had to code it somehow.

Btw, I need to have variable names set as in previous example too, but making string array for it is not a problem :)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `T1` the first table (corresponding in your example to `matrix1`), T2 the second table (`matrix1`) and soon, you can simply concatenate the components of the table this way:

```
final_table=[T1 T2 ...]
```

(the `...` means the other components

Given a set of `n` components, you can write a loop which concatenates them.

A possible implementatioin could be:

```
% Define the names of the components
t_names{1}='matrix1'
t_names{2}='matrix2'
t_names{3}='matrix3'
t_names{4}='matrix4'
% Get the number of the components
n=length(t_names)
% Initialize the final table
the_table=table
% Loop over the components to add them to the final table
for i=1:n
   the_table=[the_table table(zeros([5,5]),'VariableNames', t_names(i))]
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is also good solution so i have accepted your answer. However on Mathworks i got much simpler solution, so i want to post it here too if anyone needs that:



`args=cell(1,n);
 args(:)={zeros([5,5])};

table1 = table(args{:});`